# How to sort lexicographically array of strings JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lexicographic

How to sort lexicographically  array of e.g. [aa bb cc dd ee] where the you take the first lexicographically smallest name and append it to the lexicographically largest name, Then take the second lexicographically smallest name and append it to the second lexicographically largest name. And if you have odd number of elements like here cc the output i guess should be eeaaccddbb as a whole string. There is no function i found in Mozilla Developer tools for lexicographically  array. And if they are even number of elements of array just to return the corresponding concatenations.

Comment: please add some example to highlight the problem - and some code, you tried.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: so `["aa", "bb", "cc"]` becomes `"ccbbaa"`, `["aa", "cc", "bb"]` is sorted to `["aa", "bb", "cc"]` then becomes `"ccbbaa"` too and `["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]` becomes `"ddaabbcc"` ?

Comment: @jonatjano apperantly ["aa", "bb", "cc"] becomes first ["ccaa","bb"] then ["ccaabb"]

and the example above in my description:
["eeaa","cc","ddbb"] then ["eeaacc", "ddbb"] and lastly ["eeaaccddbb"]

Comment: it's you who's asking you should know what you want a output :p

Comment: @jonatjano well that is lexicographically  definition and example on internet. This is how it works but if you work in Java there is compareTo method here i am thinking something on the lines of localeCompare and sort but no idea how i was hoping there is something or someone that faced similar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something good :p

```js
function weirdSortConcat(arr) {
  // sort lexicaly by default
  // to be exact sort by char code so digits(0-9) are before maj(A-Z) which are before min(a-z) 
  arr.sort()
  
  let output = ""

  // for half of the array
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(arr.length / 2); i++) {
    // take starting at the end then starting by the start
    output += arr[arr.length - i - 1] + arr[i]
  }
  
  // if length is odd add last element to output
  if (arr.length % 2 === 1) {
    output += arr[Math.floor(arr.length / 2)]
  }
  
  return output
}

console.log(weirdSortConcat(["aa", "bb", "cc"]))
console.log(weirdSortConcat(["aa", "cc", "bb"]))
console.log(weirdSortConcat(["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]))
```